# Texture Paint doesn't work in 3D view

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, roughness

**Problem:** I'm trying to paint roughness and later different colors on a car body. I clicked 'Unwrap'in the UV editor and went to Texture paint. I've created a texture for the roughness and connected it into the material. When I started painting in 3D view, nothing happened except a few huge transitions at unwanted places. Although, when I painted on the unwrapped mesh it worked (however, there's still some problem at the rear). I am relatively new to texturing / unwrapping so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. Usually in tutorials after unwrapping and setting the texture it's possible to draw/paint directly on the model.
If it makes any difference, the model has subsurf. modifier, boolean and mirror on it.

**Question:** How could I paint on the actual model so that I can see what I'm doing? Which step I am missing?

[image]

Comment: hello, please pack your images and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: hello.  I have answered a very similar question in the past.  check out this link to see if my past answer helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200366/missing-texture/200374#200374

Comment: Double check normal direction as well as uv island overlap for starters. In the 3d view, zooming out with a decent brush turns it into a huge brush area which then will slow you down because the computer needs to process a large number of pixels per paint dab/stroke, so important to reduce the brush size in relation to the number of pixels under the cursor in view.

Comment: Thanks!! I recalculated the normals, same issue. I also followed the steps in the previous answer but still doesn't work. I guess I might need to check on a simpler file if still keeps happening. for now, I have no other idea.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Mode > Mesh > Normals > Flip. Your normals should be facing the outside.
To check normal direction in 3D Viewport > Overlays > Normals > Display Normals.